# Superscript any character symbol code?

Tags: android, button, text, symbols

I was searching for x^y symbol code, with no luck. I am wondering if symbol code for superscript y (or any char form a-z) exist?

In this case:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bPow"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="x^y" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

Android textview supports HTML and you can easily put X<sup>Y</sup> on a button

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bPow);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>Y</sup>"));
```

If you want to Adjust the Size of Font. According to android.text.Html (on GrepCode), you may use  for smaller text, as  only supports color and face attributes.

Try this

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bPow);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup><small>Y</small></sup>"));
```

Else sometimes there is a chance to get the text cut out in some screens.

Likewise if you want a subscript use the "sub" tag. Thanks Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

try this, you can do it using this snippet:

```
yourWidget.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>Y</sup>"));
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) but x is smaller then y. Should I try `font-size:` inside of html?

Will vote up, but can't yet.

Comment: i didn't face it..you can give it a try..:)

Comment: Nop, not working :) thanks anyway, I'll be good with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are superscripted i and n:

1ⁱ 2ⁿ